# Passing params from alsa application to kernel driver

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, alsa

I try to follow the path of parameters setting from linux user space (arecord/aplay) down to kernel driver. Let's take arecords --period-size as an example.

It all starts in `set_params` function in `aplay.c`:

```
if (period_time > 0)
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_time_near(handle, params, &period_time, 0);
else
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &period_frames, 0);
```

The function `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near()` is defined in [pcm.c : 5186](alsa-lib https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/blob/master/src/pcm/pcm.c#L5186), and here my headache starts... This function starts a chain of calls to other functions which doesn't make much sense to me and doesn't seem to be leading to any end call of driver.

There is `_end` label so I skipped all calls like `snd_pcm_hw_param_set_min()` or `snd_pcm_hw_param_set_max()` and went to `snd_pcm_hw_param_set_last()` hoping for some driver invocation like:

```
drv->hw_params_set(...);
```

but instead I found an end call to:

```
MASK_INLINE unsigned int snd_mask_min(const snd_mask_t *mask)
{
    int i;
    assert(!snd_mask_empty(mask));
    for (i = 0; i < MASK_SIZE; i++) {
        if (mask->bits[i])
            return ffs(mask->bits[i]) - 1 + (i << 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where return values shall be the parameter set.

So to summarize, I found alsa-lib to be very difficult to read and understand. Maybe I am lacking some knowledge though. My question is simple, how is user space parameter passed to kernel driver. Can you provide a software path showing interfaces called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hw_params` structure contains a *configuration space*, which is a description of all possible configurations that the device can support. Numeric parameters are described as intervals (i.e., min and max), access and format as bitmasks.

When you change one parameter, the library calls the kernel driver (`SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_REFINE`) to adjust all the other parameters in the `hw_params` structure that depend on the changed parameter.

After you have reduced the configuration space to the configuration you actually want, you call `snd_pcm_hw_params()` (→ `SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_PARAMS`) to actually configure the device for those parameters. (If some parameter has not been reduced to a single value, `snd_pcm_hw_params()` will choose a random one.)

---

`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_xxx_near()` is more complex because there is no `SET_NEAR` ioctl. This function tries to adjust the interval so that either its maximum or its minimum is the desired value, and then check whether the actual maximum or minimum is nearer.

For example, assume a device that supports period sizes of 1024, 2048, 4096, and 8192 frames. Initially, the interval is described as [1024, 8192]. When you call `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(4000)`, the `snd_pcm_hw_param_set_near()` helper function calls `set_min(4000)` and `set_max(4000)` (on separate copies of the `hw_params` structure), so the intervals are [1024, 4000] and [4000, 8192]; after refining, the driver returns the intervals [1024, 2048] and [4096, 8192]. `snd_pcm_hw_param_set_near()` then sees that 4096 is nearest to the desired calue, so it then calls `set_first` on the second interval, which results in [4096, 4096].

Comment: This answers my question but only partially. I still don't see the end call to kernel driver interface. Inside `_snd_pcm_hw_param_set_first()` which you mentioned there is nothing but some mask setup. So I still don't understand how this newly passed parameter is sent down to driver?

Comment: The kernel call happens in `_refine`.

Comment: Do you mean `snd_mask_refine_first()`? There is nothing but mask manipulations like `snd_mask_empty(mask)` or `snd_mask_leave(mask, snd_mask_min(mask));`

Comment: `snd_pcm_hw_refine()` → `snd_pcm_hw_hw_refine()`  → `hw_refine_call()`

Comment: Now I see thanks a lot! Although I still feel like it is over complicated. BTW: I see in the `hw_refine_call()` they use  `ioctl(pcm_hw->fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_REFINE, params);` can you tell how the driver registered itself prior so now application can use `pcm_hw->fd` to talk with it?

Comment: That would be a different question.